# "Canvas" methods doesn't work in itemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, itemscontrol

Canvas methods always work when they are in a canvas tag, but When you tryna use them in an itemsControl, they sometimes stop working. here's an example:

```
<ItemsControl>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Click="Button_Click">Text</Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
   
    </ItemsControl>
```

xaml.cs file

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(Canvas.GetTop(sender as Button).ToString());
    }
```

Here messagebox returns Nan and I don't know the reason. You can't use SetTop or left method either. Can you help?

**Edit:** **Here's another interesting thing**
if I give a name to an element it does work, but I don't want that because the names aren't available in the itemTemplate.

here's the code:

```
 <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SomeList}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
   <Button x:Name="Btn" Click="Button_Click">Text</Button>
   
    </ItemsControl>
```

xaml.cs file

```
 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(Canvas.GetTop(Btn).ToString());
    }
```

Comment: What do you expect `Canvas.GetTop(sender as Button)` to return when you haven't set the `Canvas.Top` attached property for the `Button`...?

Comment: but why the second example works?

Comment: The Button is not a direct child of the Canvas in the ItemsPanel. Getting or setting any Canvas attached propertiues has no effect.

Comment: Yeah, but the second example some how works. I don't know why??!!

Comment: Works in what way? What is your actual question/issue?

Comment: I mentioned two examples. if the you give a name to the button,  you can easily use Canvas methods by it's name but when you are binding it, you can't call the names

Comment: You should use an `ItemContainerStyle` and bind to a property of the data object to define its absolute positon within the `Canvas`. See my answer for an example.

Answer (score 1):

To position define the absolute position of the element in the `ItemTemplate`,  you should bind the `Canvas.Top` attached property of the container to a property of the type of objects in the `SomeList` collection:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SomeList}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Top}" />
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Click="Button_Click">Text</Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

`SomeList` should be an `IEnumerable<T>` where the type `T` has a `Top` property of type `double`:

```
public class Item
{
    public double Top { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but how to update the location. can u send the code if u don't mind?

Comment: You set the `Top` property to a different value. If you intend to do this dynamically at runtime, the `Item` class should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raise change notifications.

Comment: but how to change top property in the view? this is my whole question idea that I couldn't explain well

Comment: In the view? `<Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="100" />`?